# Ubuntu do-release-upgrade checking incorrect address - how do I change where it is looking?

Tags: ubuntu

I was running ubuntu 12.04; I ran do-release-upgrade (without any options), and for reasons which remain unclear, it decided to upgrade to 12.10 (even though I did NOT pass it the -d option) rather than 13.04 or 14.04.  lsb_release -a currently confirms that I am running 12.10, even though my login prompt still claims I am running 12.04.

As of right now, my sources list is still set to old-releases precise (I ran into nothing but problems with quantal set, but I can put it back, or change from old-releases to archive, which also has done nothing but cause problems).  Nonetheless, when I run do-release-upgrade, it looks in archive for saucy.  Naturally, it does not find it - saucy is in old-releases, but there is nothing in archive until trusty.

While I would love to tell do-release-upgrade what release to upgrade to, I am under the impression this is impossible, so my question is how I tell do-release-upgrade where to look for saucy, i.e. in old-releases, rather than archive.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do about it. You can edit sources.list file but this may not fix anything for you. Also you can't upgrade to latest release directly. Here is a link for you where it is explained why:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/779189/how-to-upgrade-a-server-from-12-04-to-16-04

Comment: I have tried editing sources.list, but do-release-upgrade appears to reliably ignore whatever I put in there.